# Java REST Multi-Node API design

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to REST design patterns. I am trying to write an API with following design in mind.

GET http://www.example.com/**customers**/33245/**orders**/8769/**lineitems**/1

I am able to write basic REST services with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey:

GET|PUT|DELETE http://www.example.com/customers/{id}

Any tutorial that explains how we should do such multi-node routing in Java would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Kush

Comment: I believe Jersey can support you with multiple `@PathParams` in your `@Path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably go with something like this (this is a snippet from the resource class):

```
...
@GET
@Path("customers/{customer-id}/orders/{order-id}/lineitems/{lineitem-id}")
public Response get(@PathParam("customer-id") String customerId, @PathParam("order-id") String orderId, @PathParam("lineitem-id") String lineItemId) {
    // fetch logic goes here...
}
...
```

Comment: I am able to do the same now along with regex expressions. Thank you.